# Casperjs get proxy

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Is there a way to get proxy from casperjs script in runtime.
For example, if script has been run as casperjs `--proxy=127.0.0.1:1111 --proxy-type=socks5 script.js` I want to get proxy from script.js using something `casper.cli.get('proxy')`

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible since phantomjs itself does not expose this commandline option to the script.

Running

```
phantomjs --proxy-type=socks5
> phantom
```

shows that the `args` property is still empty. There doesn't seem to be a way around that. You may want to write a feature request on [github](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/new).